# Checking if an Object in Array is Another Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to access an array that I stored inside of $_SESSION. I've printed out the count and contents of $_SESSION just before the loop for good measure.

```
// $_SESSION info.
Length: 4
Array
(
    [loggedIn] => 1 
    [total] => 0 
    [plates] => Array ([0] => plates [1] => 14 [2] => 5) 
    [backpack] => Array ([0] => backpack [1] => 78 [2] => 1)
)
```

Here we can clearly see that the last two objects are in fact arrays. But, when I try the `is_array` method,

```
//PHP code
$length = count($_SESSION);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
    if(is_array($_SESSION[$i])){
        echo 'session '.$i.' is an array.<br />';
    }
    else{
        echo 'session '.$i.' is not an array.<br />';
    }
}
```

all of the objects return false.

```
session 0 is not an array.
session 1 is not an array.
session 2 is not an array.
session 3 is not an array.
```

The API says that `is_array` is supposed to find, «whether the given variable is an array». But, I guess I must be misunderstanding something here...

Comment: Your array is keyed and not indexed! Use `foreach`. $_SESSION[0..3] doen't exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use `for` loop. Use `foreach`.

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
        echo 'session '.$key.' is an array.<br />';
    } else {
        echo 'session '.$key.' is not an array.<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're trying to iterate through an associative array with numeric indices instead of the appropriate keys.  Try this instead:

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_array($value)){
        echo 'session '.$key.' is an array.<br />';
    }
    else{
        echo 'session '.$key.' is not an array.<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key=>$val){
    if(is_array($val)){
    // code here
    }
}
```